# Build error while using WindowsAzure.Servicebus package version 4.1.10 on a .NET 4.5 application

Tags: c#, azure, nuget-package, azure-servicebus-queues

I seem to be unable to use this library in project

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ClassLibrary2   \Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2\EntityListener.cs  24  Active

```
using WindowsAzure.Servicebus;
```

I installed using nuget packet manager, and it is defined in my packages.config file.  Why can I not use it?

Packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="4.1.10" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: You sure that is the correct namespace to use? I think you need `using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#3-send-messages-to-the-queue))

Comment: There is no servicebus in that one.

Comment: what version of the package did you install? You sure the package installed correctly? Can you post your actual code?

Comment: I downloaded the version compatible with asp.net 4.5, as the project requires this.  So not the same at your source @PeterBons

Comment: Do you get any warnings on build?

Comment: I get an error that it cannot find it  CS0246

Comment: Ok, but no warnings at all? Strange. What type are you trying to access from the namespace?

Comment: I am just trying write to an azure queue, but since i Am using .NET 4.5 i seem to have some problems. I should use this https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.iqueueclient?view=azure-dotnet

To establish a connection to the queue, but since i Am using 4.5 I am not able to install,  Micosoft.azure.servicebus, which has an .netStandard 2.0

Comment: I need to use that, but cannot use it.. that is the whole problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your .NET project version **is exactly 4.5** (not 4.5.x), you will need to fall back to WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package **version 4.1.3**. Moreover, this

Here is the packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="4.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

In addition, the correct namespace to use is the following:

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
```

Find below a sample .NET 4.5 Console Application that sends a message to an Azure Service Bus Queue. Please note this is just a sample and it is not production ready code. I hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace ServiceBusSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ConnectionString = "your service bus connection string";
            const string QueueName = "your service bus queue name";
            string message = "Hello World!";
            string sessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            SendMessage(ConnectionString, QueueName, sessionId, message).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task SendMessage(string connectionString, string queueName, string sessionId, string message, string correlationId = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Service bus connection string cannot be null, empty or whitespace.");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queueName))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Service bus queue name cannot be null, empty or whitespace.");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionId))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Session id cannot be null, empty or whitespace.");
                }

                QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

                BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
                brokeredMessage.SessionId = sessionId;

                await queueClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
            }
            catch
            {
                // TODO: Handle exception appropriately (including logging)
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```